# PostgreSQL table structure design to minimize table size

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I have a single table that could get very large. Because of the simple structure, it will eventually get unmanageable. How can I change the table structure so that it reduces table size while speeding up writes and searches?

It has four fields, one being a `name` field. The search is on the `name` field using this SQL as an example:

```
SELECT id, name, flavour
FROM mytable
WHERE name LIKE '%$1%'
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 20
```

So this is a two part question:

1. Will streaming incoming items for this table to a breakout of first letter ('a' for 'alpha_item' into the 'a' table) actually reduce the overhead and increase stability?
2. Is this approach good for applying the same search to 26 tables and consolidating records for presentation? It sounds very heavy.

This is the only way I see managing such a large table while also spreading the workload onto different tables.  I'm sure there's something to be gained here, but I'm not sure if this is the best way of spreading information around for stability and speed increase on a search.

Comment: Why do you think a "simple structure" results in a table being "unmanageable"?  If the table only has three column, I don't see how that could be "minimized" any more. And how big is "large" anyway. How many rows do you expect?

Comment: To improve the performance of a wildcard search like the one you have shown, you will need a [trigram index](https://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/)

Comment: if you want to shard the table. it males little difference on how you do that if you need to support wildcard searches on `name`.  partitioning on `id` might be a win.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Portability, to start.  Large files are just that.  Spreading out to multiple tables might have an advantage.  That's exactly why I'm asking.  This IS a DB forum.  How many rows do I expect?  Millions, eventually.  Does a table like that eventually stop at a certain count?

Comment: @Jasen That's what I was thinking, given the wildcard on both ends.  If wildcard on the tail, there might be a different approach.

Comment: "Millions of rows" is hardly "very large" nowadays - that does not qualify as "unmanageable". And what do you mean with "large files"? Are you importing binary data into those tables? Are you asking about [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) when you mention "spreading out to multiple tables"? Your sample SQL does not indicate anything about "multiple tables" or "large files".

Comment: "nowadays"?  What does that mean?  Comparing to other deployments is detrimental.  The needs of the project are just that.  The integrity of any file has nothing to do with other people's solutions.  No binary data.  I am asking about a solution based on a growing table with a wildcard search, as stated.  A "growing table" is exactly what I stated, which grows into a "large file".  What part is confusing?  Please, some detail.  I think you're quite confused.

Comment: postgresql doesn't make large files (2GiB max), large tables may have several disk files.